# Unexpected system shutdown with low battery UPS status

Tags: ups, nut

I have `nut` which installed on Debian 8 host. The host is connected with UPS. In general everything works as expected. If UPS works on line, `upsc` shows the corresponding status. If UPS works on battery, `upsc` again shows the corresponding status. But if UPS has low battery status, `upsc` shows the corresponding status and (!) host shuts down even if I haven't asked `nut` for such behaviour.

Which part of `nut` (`upsmon`, `upssched`, or something else) is responsible for such behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like you should look at all the various configuration files including nut.conf and the config file for the ups package.

Comment: Read the [user manual pdf](http://networkupstools.org/docs/user-manual.pdf). `/etc/ups/upsmon.conf` is where you config what to do on low battery.

Comment: @meuh, thanks, I've found that setting of `FINALDELAY` from `/etc/ups/upsmon.conf` to large number can be workaround. Also I can prevent shut down by changing `SHUTDOWNCMD`. But I can't realize why `nut` shutdown my host even if I have not asked about this? Another words: does `nut` has variable like `SHUTDOWN_IF_LOW_BATTERY 0|1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Network UPS Tools User Manual [pdf](http://networkupstools.org/docs/user-manual.pdf), *section 6.3.1 Shutdown design*, it describes the algorithm used. The important point is that if the ups is on battery, and also the battery charge is low, this is **critical**, and means that soon there will be no power at all, so a shutdown is started.

On low battery, upsmon sets "FSD" (forced shutdown sequence), generates a
NOTIFY_SHUTDOWN event, waits FINALDELAY seconds, creates the POWERDOWNFLAG
file `/etc/killpower`, calls SHUTDOWNCMD. These values are set in `/etc/ups/upsmon.conf`.

On some ups devices, you can change the value of the low battery signal point. To list the variables for, say, device `myups`:

```
$ upsrw myups
[battery.charge.low]
Remaining battery level when UPS switches to LB (percent)
Type: STRING
Maximum length: 5
Value: 20
...
```

This example shows low battery is signalled when 20% charge is left. To change this to 10% you need the nut user and password you configured in `/etc/ups/upsd.users`, then you can do, eg:

```
$ upsrw -u mynutuser -p mynutpassword -s battery.charge.low=10 myups
OK

$ upsrw myups | grep -A4 battery.charge.low
[battery.charge.low]
Remaining battery level when UPS switches to LB (percent)
Type: STRING
Maximum length: 5
Value: 10
```